# Adding create-react-app WITH Router to existing Javascript project

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-router

I have written a create-react-app application using routing and as a standalone react application it works fine. I am writing it with regards to integrating it with our existing application which is a straightforward javascript/php/html application.
Issue is that without routing I can bundle up the react app, place it into my existing .php file and it all works fine.
As soon as I introduce routing, my existing application stops working and there are no errors.

This is what I have setup

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './Address/Page';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Address/Page** which is imported in index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./AddressTemp";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
          
          
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I use webpack to bundle up the code into bundle.min.js and place the code into my php

php code

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    

</head>
    <body style="margin-top: 0px;">
        
        <?php $title = 'Address Maintenance';
              include 'include/header.php'; ?>
        <div id="square<?php echo $MenuOn; ?>">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading"> Addresses </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="root"></div>
                </div>
            </div>    
            
        </div>
        <script src="bundle.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <?php include 'include/footer.php'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated
Harj

I am a loss. Its definitely to do with routing. Without routing I can bundle, place in my existing app and it all works. Introduce routing and its stops working without any errors

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do with 2 different types of routing. 
React project starts from ```root``` of ```const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));``` so you can try to place ```root``` id where you need. Maybe this might help.

Comment: *Outside of php page (i.e. route).

Comment: What is the URL in the browser when running your main application when you are attempting to access your React app?

Comment: @SurajNeupane - sorry I dont undertsand what you mean

Comment: @DrewReese - my existing application url is http://localhost/basefolder/main.php where main.php is the php I am running with embedded react bundle.min.js

Comment: I see. See if adding something like `basename="/basefolder/main.php"` to the `Router` component gets things working for you.

Comment: @Harj sorry but, what are you trying to accomplish? If you want to run react in PHP, you are not supposed to implement the route. You can find more about it here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

If you are trying to run both PHP and react routes in a project, then you can alternate routes from web servers. 

If it's something else, please let us know.

Comment: @DrewReese I will read up on basename and report back.

Comment: @SurajNeupane I am NOT running React in PHP. All I am doing is bundling up my react code into something like bundle.min.js and then placing that minified javascript into my a html in my main application.  Apologies for mis-labeling the html code as php code. It is not php code. Its a simple html which has a div "root" which should be used by the bundle.min.js as thats what that renders.

Comment: @SurajNeupane sorry just to add my code works perfectly without routing. As soon as routing is put in it stops. No errors so that suggests that my main application is not finding the route code .

Comment: @DrewReese I dont think basename is going to solve my issue. The whole point of bundling the react code into one single minified js was because I could just plonk it into my html code. The WHOLE react code is in bundle.min.js so no point in basename as I am already pointing at it in my html. Logically it seems I need to somehow bundle up the other routes so that I have bundle.min.js and maybe home.min.js. Then point to Home somehow. Very frustrating I thought someone must have done this already moons ago as it isnt exactly something weird I am doing.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it might just be `basename="/basefolder"` since that seems to be the directory the main application is running from, e.g. where `main.php` is being served. The `basename` router prop is used when the React app code isn't running from the root directory, i.e. `"/"`, it makes all routes and links operate *relative* from the specified base path, i.e. from `"/basefolder"`.

Answer (score 1):

This is been a bigger struggle than I had imagined. Seems no one has had my issue of integrating React code with existing application where React code has routes. I have read 2 days of posts on various forums and literally nothing. So for anyone who has my issue, which seems no one, I will post what has worked for after hours of manipulating code.
This is for anyone using React-RouterV6 and has an existing application written in Javascript with a PHPv8 backend.
The issue is the code MUST work in standalone React envrionment and whne bundled up it must work embedded in existing Javascript app.

**Address/Page** with multiple routes

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./AddressTemp";
import Maintenance from ".components/Maintenance";

let location="";
let homePath="";
if (process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_FOLDER===""){
    location="/base";
    homePath="/main.php";  
}
else{
    location="/";
    homePath="/";
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router basename={location}>
      
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={homePath} element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/maintenance" element={<Maintenance />} />
          
          
        </Routes>
        </Suspense>
        
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There are 2 important parts to the above. The introduction of env and the usage of basename.
process.env retrieves a dotenv file (.env) from the base directory of the application. With regards to React standalone this file exists where package.json lives ie base directory. In it we have the following

**.env**

`REACT_APP_BASE_FOLDER=http://localhost/base/`

For this purpose this is just a marker but I have used it in my React code to get access to my existing application code; but thats another story.

So now Address/Page knows whether its coming from React standalone or my main application environment.

The tricky part was to work out what main application needed.
For react both basename and homepath is "/".
For main application basename is the base directory of the application and homepath is the main application program which has the embedded react code in it.
And that is it. It all works.